# frameworks for separate web app and database server

Tags: php, python, database, web

I'm having a hard time on choosing which platform will I be using in creating a separate web app and database. What could be the possible and more easier to use in creating a separate web app and database? I'm thinking of using PHP for the web app and the database server will be python. Is it gonna be convenient? Or should I use only the php for web app and connect it to the separated database server?

Comment: This question is too broad.

Comment: Use PHP/Python/Ruby/Perl/ASP.NET/etc. and connect directly to database server.

Comment: @furas wouldn't that be vulnerable for hackers to access the database directly?

Comment: Nobody is perfect. I think most (small) portals/webpages access database directly - for **best performance**. But webpage should has access to database only using database account with restricted privileges (restricted IP address, restricted login, restricted SQL functions). And you have to test page for any vulnerabilities (SQL, XSS, wrong page name, wrong arguments, not showing errors messages, etc.).